# HTTP Header Authorization

Tags: swift, http, header, authorization

I already read some other answers regarding HTTP Authorization Header with Swift but I just can't figure it out.

With c# I'm able to do a HTTP request with

```
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("user", "APIkey");                
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var request = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.xx.com", null );
```

now I'm trying to do the same request with Swift, but it fails:

```
guard let urlg = URL(string: "https://api.xx.com") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
var request = URLRequest(url: urlg)
let username = "user"
let password = "APIKey"
let base64encoded = "\(username): \(password)".data(using: .isoLatin1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""  
request.addValue("\(base64encoded)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your Authentification value? I'd expect: `request.addValue("\(user) \(password)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")` Cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-headers-authenticationheadervalue-ctor(system-string-system-string)

Comment: Yes, the username and key values are corect, as they are both identical in the .NET and Swift request. Somehow Swift generates a different header information.

Comment: It's not there, but did you set "POST" for the method? Since currently, your request is a GET

Comment: Turns out u were right, had to insert username and password directly without encoding